# calling javascript function in iframe from window.opener

Tags: javascript, iframe, window.opener

I have a function in an iFrame (same domain) that I want to call from a popup.

So basically I want to do something like        window.opener.document.getElementById('topFrame').contentWindow.setActive('1');

In the window.opener of the popup, i have an iframe with the id "topFrame" (and name "topFrame" in case that's a better solution) in which the function setActive('1') must be executed.
However the code stated above does not work and google isn't really helping in finding solutions for this specific case.

Anyone has an idea?

Thx

Comment: At which point does it not work? Have you tried logging to verify that you have successfully got a reference to the iframe, etc? If you can pinpoint which "dot" is breaking it, it would help debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your line should actually work and the problem probably a timing issue: most likely your iframe hasn't finished loading at the time you are trying to call its function. Placing your call after `load` or `DomReady` should do the trick.

(You can also experiment by wrapping your call in a timeout and see if it works at a later point).

Answer (score 0):

if you are opening the pop up from the iframe window then you should use

```
window.opener.setActive('1');
```

because window.opener will itself return you the iframe window .it might be the case because i was also committing this mistake. hope your problem is solved :)